# How can I make odoo service run with certain flags?

Tags: odoo, ubuntu-16.04, odoo-10

I'm trying to set the configuration file of my odoo server to certain file, I know that running odoo with the `-c <path>` or `--config <path>` will do the work, but I'm running it in the server like a service so I can't do this, neither adding the configs to /etc/odoo/odoo.conf because I need 2 configuration files.

Does someone knows how can I can make odoo service run with certain flags(-c and --load)

Here's my config at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf

```
[options]
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/distpackages/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo/addons/odoodoto
admin_passwd = XXXXXXXXXXXX
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo
db_host = False
db_name = False
db_password = False
db_port = 5432
db_user = False
demo = {}
log_level = warn
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
logrotate = True
proxy_mode = False
```

And my second config:

```
[connector-options]
workers = 4
export ODOO_CONNECTOR_CHANNELS=root:5
export ODOO_CONNECTOR_PORT=8069
log-level = warn
```

And the `--load=web,connector` is the other flag I need

Comment: Show me the entire files and i may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file I was looking for is `/etc/systemd/system/odoo.service` there you can specify in the [Service] options something like this `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/odoo --load=web,connector -c /somedir/odoo-server.conf`.

You can also configure some of the service settings in /etc/init.d/odoo like [George Daramouskas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2583086/george-daramouskas) sayed but I don't really know how and if you can add the flags I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into many details of the init systems of Ubuntu, you should have a bash script inside `/etc/init.d` (probably `/etc/init.d/odoo-server`).

Inside that file insert a line:

`DAEMON_OPTS="-c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf"`

Use commas to pass more parameters

Comment: My init.d file is a little bit different, here is a fragment: 
`DAEMON=/usr/bin/odoo
NAME=odoo
DESC=odoo
CONFIG=/etc/odoo/odoo.conf
LOGFILE=/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
PIDFILE=/var/run/${NAME}.pid
USER=odoo
#DAEMON_OPTS='--load=web,web_kanban,connector , -c /opt/odoo/addons/odoodoto/tdt_connector_woocommerce/odoo-server.conf'

export LOGNAME=$USER

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
set -e
function _start() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $USER:$USER --background --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON -- --config $CONFIG --logfile $LOGFILE
}`

Comment: The daemon_opts is commented out , remove the #

Comment: I commented it out cause it wasn't changing anything, should't it be the DAEMON var instead? DAEMON_OPTS isn't being called from anywhere